# JBoss automatic .war redeployment can't start application properly - Error on Keycloak redirection

Tags: deployment, jboss, war

A colleague of mine wants to automate their JBoss (JBoss EAP v7.4.0) deployments.
So far the process they followed manually was:

1. Shutdown Jboss entirely
2. Copy the new `.war` file under `/jboss-eap-7.4.0/standalone/deployments` directory
3. Restart the server by executing `standalone.sh`

This process, although a bit 'dump', manages to deploy the application with no issues.

I on the other hand, tried to make use of JBoss's auto-redeployment feature, so I simply pasted the new .war file under the `/jboss-eap-7.4.0/standalone/deployments` directory.
JBoss indeed picks up the new .war and automatically starts the redeployment process.

From the server.log file, it seems at first that the application deploys successfully.
However when I try to access it from my browser, it crashes and gives a code 500 response (See error logs at the end of the post). The expected behavior would be to redeploy me to keycloak in order to login.

The exact same error occurs if I try to manually `undeploy` and `deploy` the .war from the `jboss.cli`.

Any hints on the issue?

I can't figure out if the error is on the server or the application side.

It seems a bit odd that it should require a full JBoss server restart in order for the application to be properly deployed.

Thank you in advance.

### Server logs:

> 2022-06-14 17:22:25,850 WARN  [org.apache.jcp.xml.dsig.internal.dom.DOMReference] (default task-1) The input bytes to the digest operation are null. This may be due to a problem with the Reference URI or its Transforms.
>
> > 2022-06-14 17:22:25,879 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-1) UT005023: Exception handling request to /myapplication: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not create authentication request.
> > at org.keycloak.keycloak-saml-adapter-core@15.0.2//org.keycloak.adapters.saml.AbstractInitiateLogin.challenge(AbstractInitiateLogin.java:64)
> > at org.keycloak.keycloak-saml-wildfly-elytron-adapter@15.0.2//org.keycloak.adapters.saml.elytron.ElytronHttpFacade.noAuthenticationInProgress(ElytronHttpFacade.java:123)
> > at org.keycloak.keycloak-saml-wildfly-elytron-adapter@15.0.2//org.keycloak.adapters.saml.elytron.KeycloakHttpServerAuthenticationMechanism.evaluateRequest(KeycloakHttpServerAuthenticationMechanism.java:125)
> > at org.wildfly.security.elytron-private@1.15.3.Final-redhat-00001//org.wildfly.security.http.util.SetMechanismInformationMechanismFactory$1.evaluateRequest(SetMechanismInformationMechanismFactory.java:119)
> > at org.wildfly.security.elytron-private@1.15.3.Final-redhat-00001//org.wildfly.security.http.util.SocketAddressCallbackServerMechanismFactory$1.evaluateRequest(SocketAddressCallbackServerMechanismFactory.java:82)
> > at org.wildfly.security.elytron-private@1.15.3.Final-redhat-00001//org.wildfly.security.auth.server.SecurityIdentityServerMechanismFactory$1.evaluateRequest(SecurityIdentityServerMechanismFactory.java:85)
> > at org.wildfly.security.elytron-private@1.15.3.Final-redhat-00001//org.wildfly.security.http.HttpAuthenticator$AuthenticationExchange.authenticate(HttpAuthenticator.java:326)
> > at org.wildfly.security.elytron-private@1.15.3.Final-redhat-00001//org.wildfly.security.http.HttpAuthenticator$AuthenticationExchange.access$800(HttpAuthenticator.java:301)
> > at org.wildfly.security.elytron-private@1.15.3.Final-redhat-00001//org.wildfly.security.http.HttpAuthenticator.authenticate(HttpAuthenticator.java:94)
> > at org.wildfly.security.elytron-web.undertow-server@1.9.0.Final-redhat-00001//org.wildfly.elytron.web.undertow.server.SecurityContextImpl.authenticate(SecurityContextImpl.java:99)
> > at org.wildfly.security.elytron-web.undertow-server-servlet@1.9.0.Final-redhat-00001//org.wildfly.elytron.web.undertow.server.servlet.ServletSecurityContextImpl.authenticate(ServletSecurityContextImpl.java:115)
> > at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:55)
> > at io.undertow.core@2.2.5.Final-redhat-00001//io.undertow.server.handlers.DisableCacheHandler.handleRequest(DisableCacheHandler.java:33)
> > at io.undertow.core@2.2.5.Final-redhat-00001//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
> > at io.undertow.core@2.2.5.Final-redhat-00001//io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationConstraintHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationConstraintHandler.java:53)
> > at io.undertow.core@2.2.5.Final-redhat-00001//io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
> > at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
> > at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.java:59)
> > at io.undertow.core@2.2.5.Final-redhat-00001//io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
> > at org.wildfly.security.elytron-web.undertow-server-servlet@1.9.0.Final-redhat-00001//org.wildfly.elytron.web.undertow.server.servlet.CleanUpHandler.handleRequest(CleanUpHandler.java:38)
> > at io.undertow.core@2.2.5.Final-redhat-00001//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
> > at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@7.4.0.GA-redhat-00005//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
> > at io.undertow.core@2.2.5.Final-redhat-00001//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
> > at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@7.4.0.GA-redhat-00005//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.GlobalRequestControllerHandler.handleRequest(GlobalRequestControllerHandler.java:68)
> > at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.SendErrorPageHandler.handleRequest(SendErrorPageHandler.java:52)
> > at io.undertow.core@2.2.5.Final-redhat-00001//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
> > at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:269)
> > at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:78)
> > at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:133)
> > at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:130)
> > at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
> > at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
> > at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@7.4.0.GA-redhat-00005//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
> > at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@7.4.0.GA-redhat-00005//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
> > at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@7.4.0.GA-redhat-00005//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
> > at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@7.4.0.GA-redhat-00005//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
> > at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@7.4.0.GA-redhat-00005//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1530)
> > at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:249)
> > at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:78)
> > at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.5.Final-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:99)
> > at io.undertow.core@2.2.5.Final-redhat-00001//io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:387)
> > at io.undertow.core@2.2.5.Final-redhat-00001//io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:841)
> > at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
> > at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
> > at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
> > at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
> > at org.jboss.xnio@3.8.4.Final-redhat-00001//org.xnio.XnioWorker$WorkerThreadFactory$1$1.run(XnioWorker.java:1280)
> > at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
> >
> > > Caused by: org.apache.xml.serializer.utils.WrappedRuntimeException: class org.apache.xml.serializer.ToXMLSAXHandler cannot be cast to class org.apache.xml.serializer.SerializationHandler (org.apache.xml.serializer.ToXMLSAXHandler is in unnamed module of loader 'deployment.myapplication.war' @15a25903; org.apache.xml.serializer.SerializationHandler is in unnamed module of loader 'deployment.myapplication.war' @68ae4310)
> > > at deployment.myapplication.war//org.apache.xml.serializer.SerializerFactory.getSerializer(SerializerFactory.java:179)
> > > at deployment.myapplication.war//org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerIdentityImpl.createResultContentHandler(TransformerIdentityImpl.java:261)
> > > at deployment.myapplication.war//org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerIdentityImpl.transform(TransformerIdentityImpl.java:330)
> > > at org.keycloak.keycloak-saml-core@15.0.2//org.keycloak.saml.common.util.DocumentUtil.getNodeAsString(DocumentUtil.java:228)
> > > at org.keycloak.keycloak-saml-core@15.0.2//org.keycloak.saml.common.util.DocumentUtil.getDocumentAsString(DocumentUtil.java:207)
> > > at org.keycloak.keycloak-saml-core@15.0.2//org.keycloak.saml.BaseSAML2BindingBuilder.getSAMLResponse(BaseSAML2BindingBuilder.java:311)
> > > at org.keycloak.keycloak-saml-core@15.0.2//org.keycloak.saml.BaseSAML2BindingBuilder.buildHtmlPostResponse(BaseSAML2BindingBuilder.java:307)
> > > at org.keycloak.keycloak-saml-core@15.0.2//org.keycloak.saml.BaseSAML2BindingBuilder$BasePostBindingBuilder.getHtmlRequest(BaseSAML2BindingBuilder.java:172)
> > > at org.keycloak.keycloak-saml-adapter-core@15.0.2//org.keycloak.adapters.saml.SamlUtil.sendSaml(SamlUtil.java:45)
> > > at org.keycloak.keycloak-saml-adapter-core@15.0.2//org.keycloak.adapters.saml.profile.AbstractSamlAuthenticationHandler$3.sendAuthnRequest(AbstractSamlAuthenticationHandler.java:622)
> > > at org.keycloak.keycloak-saml-adapter-core@15.0.2//org.keycloak.adapters.saml.AbstractInitiateLogin.challenge(AbstractInitiateLogin.java:61)